# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object when using GTM

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-tag-manager

When I add this script to _document.tsx in my NextJs app. I starting getting errors on console when i build the application.

```
              <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
                new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
                })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');`,
            }}
          ></script>
```

This is the error that appear on my console.
[image]

Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: this happened to me as well I enabled amplitude in gtm and now it is trying to get the amplitude instance which doesn't exist and this error shows up, found this when it is flooding sentry, no solution yet

Answer (score 0):

You have to add 2 scripts that GTAG Manager gives,

1st Script - `<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src= 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f); })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-xxxxx');</script>`

2nd Iframe Script  - `<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>`

Here is the example for nextjs

1st Script will put in the HEAD tag like this -

```
 <script  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: `
         (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
         new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
         j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
         'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
         })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');
         `
          }} />
```

2nd Script will be put into the body tag, like this -

```
<Script
          strategy="afterInteractive"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
            <noscript>   <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX"
            height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
          `,
          }}
        />
```